# Update Query issue in SQL for multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to use an update query but so far it is keep failing on me and i don't understand what am i doing wrong here.  I am getting this error 'Update canceled: attempt to update a target row with values from multiple join rows'. I know the table called OTHER_TABLE has duplicate records. Here is my current query:

```
UPDATE MAINTABLE
         SET BLDG_NBR = DM.BLDG_NBR
         FROM OTHER_TABLE DM
         WHERE  MAINTABLE.BLDG_NM = DM.BLDG_NM
```

Comment: Sounds like there are multiple rows that match the condition `MAINTABLE.BLDG_NM = DM.BLDG_NM`

Comment: How can *we* resolve this? We could *guess* that the join with OTHER_TABLE produced duplicates, but you yourself already knew that. What else is there to suggest at this point other than try and make your join condition more specific? I mean, we don't see your data and you haven't explained how you would like to resolve the issue (as in "what rule should be used to decide on which of the multiple matches is to update the target row?").

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the two tables

```
UPDATE MAINTABLE
SET BLDG_NBR = DM.BLDG_NBR
FROM MAINTABLE INNER JOIN OTHER_TABLE DM
     ON MAINTABLE.BLDG_NM = DM.BLDG_NM
```

According to your comment, you have no index set on the tables and because of that it performs full table scan. Try adding index on both tables before executing the update statement,

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX MAINTABLE_BLDGNM_idx ON MAINTABLE(BLDG_NM);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX OTHERTABLE_BLDGNM_idx ON OTHER_TABLE(BLDG_NM);
```

Comment: I have done that but the query is just keep running without any results.  it seems it is not doing anything.  thanks

Comment: you don't have any index defined on the columns right? can you show the table schema of the two tables?

Comment: there is no index defined for both tables and the data type is varchar.  it is huge table and i believe both tables have duplicates.

Comment: are all records from `OTHER_TABLE` references to `MAINTABLE`?

Comment: you need to define index on each table, see my updated answer.

Comment: there are some records in other table that are not in the main table and vise versa